# .hide on any click action not relating to child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="example" style="background:yellow;height:200px;width:200px;">
 <button>Some text</button>
</div>​
```

I want `#example` to `.hide` when it's clicked, but I don't want it to `.hide` when it's child elements get clicked.

Comment: so in your example you don't want it to hide if the button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler to the `<div>` and then check if it's the target.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fqkG/1/), the `event.target` is the element that was actually clicked, but `this` is the element attached with the handler.

```
$('#example').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target === this) {
        alert('div, not button');
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```